# How center the chapter* titles

Tags: horizontal-alignment, chapters, starred-version

I want center the title "Preface" and "Abstract" only. I do not want to centralize all the chapters. I can not and I should not delete any bookstore, I need all the libraries.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{11.5pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}



\begin{document}

\chapter*{\centering Preface}


Some text
\chapter*{\centering Abstract}


\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Body}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should all chapter titles be centred, or only unnumbered chapters?

Comment: @Bernard only two, Preface and Abstract

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the title inside a `\makebox[\linewidth]`; this naturally centres it. It would not have any impact on headers or the ToC since these elements don't end up there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{Preface}}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{\makebox[\linewidth]{Abstract}}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Body}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And if you need them in the ToC, replace the `*` by `[Preface]` or `[Abstract]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Fast solution**

You could set a manual space

```
\chapter*{\hspace{.4\textwidth}Preface}
```

which puts the title almost in the middle of the page

**Reasoned solution**

Otherwise you could think of measuring the length of your title and make the thing more precise with the package `calc`

```
%PREAMBLE
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\chaplen[1]{
    \setlength\mylen{(\textwidth-\widthof{\Huge\bfseries #1})/2}
}

%... BEGIN DOCUMENT

\chaplen{Preface}
\chapter*{\hspace*{\mylen}Preface}

\chaplen{OTHER}
\chapter*{\hspace*{\mylen}OTHER}
```

[image]

FUll code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{11.5pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}

\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\chaplen[1]{
    \setlength\mylen{(\textwidth-\widthof{\Huge\bfseries #1})/2}
    }

\begin{document}

\chaplen{Preface}
\chapter*{\hspace*{\mylen}Preface}


Some text
\chaplen{Abstract}
\chapter*{\hspace*{\mylen}Abstract}


\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Body}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does not centralize well, another option?

Comment: Why you multiplied by 2?

Comment: I think it is still wrong. If it would work, it should be `(x-y)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tools from `sectsty`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{14.4pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{11.5pt}{13.8pt}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\chapterfont{\huge\bfseries\centering}
\chapter*{\centering Preface}

Some text
\chapter*{\centering Abstract}

\chapterfont{\huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Body}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]